# Wordpress agregar submenu en Custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, wordpress-plugin

me gustaria agregar un submenu en un custom post type. Ahora tengo este post type:

do_action( 'guaitacat_register_post_type' );

```
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Cameras', 'guaita-cat' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Cameras', 'guaita-cat' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Afegir camara','guaita-cat'),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Nova camara','guaita-cat'),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Editar camara','guaita-cat' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'Nova camara','guaita-cat' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Totes les cameras','guaita-cat' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'Veure camara','guaita-cat'),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Buscar camara','guaita-cat'),
        'not_found'          => __( 'Not found!','guaita-cat' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in the bin','guaita-cat' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => __('Cameras','guaita-cat'));
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'guaita-cat' ),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-media-text',
        'can_export'         => true,
        'menu_position'      => 40,
        'supports'           => array('title')
    );
    register_post_type( 'guaita-cat', $args );

    do_action( 'guaitacat_after_register_post_type' );
```

Pero cuando agrego esto para hacer el submenu, no me sale:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu'); 
    function my_admin_menu() { 
        add_submenu_page('guaita-cat', 'Genre', 'Genre', 'post', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=genre'); 
    }
```

Gracias!

Comment: Intenta [de este modo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#comment-1261). No sé por qué usas `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=genre` y no `edit.php?post_type=guaita-cat`